# Java servlets, JSP - Changing contens od DIV

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, scriptlet

I'm  writing my first bigger application and I have one issue. I have DIV and when user isn't logged (session is null) this DIV shows links for Register and Login pages but when user is logged (session exists) it should shows "Hello" + userName and link to Logout. Can someone explain me or show on example how to do it using java servlets and JSP?

I had one idea how to code it but it is very weak i think:

```
<div class="topbar">
            <%
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Object user = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("User");
            if(user == null){
                out.println("<a href="register.jsp">Register</a> <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>"); // yes, in this line is error ;(
            } else {
                out.println("Logged successfull, Hello" + user);
            }
             %> </div>
```

Comment: Here is a an [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-http-session-login-and-logout-example) application to your requirement.

Comment: Big thanks, but i'm looking for example how to show one content in div when user is logged and another when he isn't , also i want to see how to code it in java classes instead using java code jsp,

Answer (score 1):

You must replace a string in `out.println()` method

```
"<a href="register.jsp">Register</a> <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>"
```

to the following one:

```
"<a href=\"register.jsp\">Register</a> <a href=\"login.jsp\">Login</a>"
```

You should use `\"` to write `"` inside the quotes. Otherwise, you'll get a compile error.

---

You should write Java code marginally in your jsp-files. All of the logic must be, for example, in controllers.

Comment: It is \ not / :) . Also i'm looking for good example how to code it in java classes instead jsp, if you have this one please share. Greetings